# How to iterate between two datatables in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable

I have two datatables (dtSF and CurveFitTable) that contain two different values which I have to multiply. The objective is to produce a datatable that contains the product of two values from two different datatables. The twist is, the CurveFitTable came from different csv files in a directory which I already defined.

What I intended to do is to have a datatable like the adjustedCopy table in the image below. Unfortunately, what I'm getting is a single datatable which kept on being overwritten and whenever I attempt to databind it to the grid, the datatable seems to be empty. Please help. T.T

[image]

This is my code:

```
     Dim adjusteddemandtable As New DataTable()
    Dim adjustedcopy As New DataTable()
    Dim multiply_SF As Double
    Dim adjusted_Demand As Double
    Dim initial_Demand As Double
    Dim basecurvestamp As Date

    adjusteddemandtable.Columns.Add("Base Curve", GetType(Date))
    adjusteddemandtable.Columns("Base Curve").SetOrdinal(0)
    adjusteddemandtable.Columns.Add("Adjusted_Demand", GetType(Double))
    Dim CurveFitTatble As New DataTable()

   Try

        For Each filename As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(BackUpDirectory)

            CurveFitTatble = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(filename)

            For Each row2 As DataRow In dtSF.Rows()
                For Each row As DataRow In CurveFitTatble.Rows()
                    initial_Demand = row(1)
                    basecurvestamp = row(0)
                    multiply_SF = row2(0)
                    adjusted_Demand = multiply_SF * initial_Demand

                    Dim rowa As DataRow = adjusteddemandtable.Rows.Add()
                    rowa(0) = basecurvestamp
                    rowa(1) = adjusted_Demand
                Next
            Next

            adjustedcopy.Merge(adjusteddemandtable, True, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey)  

        Next

        GridView1.DataSource = adjustedcopy
        GridView1.DataBind()

    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorMessageBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

I think, I'm missing something or overlooked an important step. Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is visual basic not c#

Comment: um, yes. sorry. the tag was suggested.

Comment: no worries I was just highlight the tag change

Comment: Do you only want to multiply values from rows at corresponding indexes, e.g. the two values from the first row in each table and then the two values from the second row in each table but not the first row in one table with the second row in the other?  If so then you should be using a single `for` loop, not nested `foreach` loops.  Nested loops means that you'll combine every row in one table with every row in the other table, i.e. if you have M rows in one table and N rows in the other then your result will have (M * N) rows.

Comment: You mean I should use: For i As Integer = 0 To DataTables.Rows.Count? Okay, I will try it now. Thanks :D

Comment: Hi @jmcilhinney, I just did what you said and instead of three nested `Foreach` loops, I used three loops using integers. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did what @jmcilhinney told me (that is to replace nested `Foreach` nested loop. Here is my new code (and fortunately, it is working as its expected output requires)

```
 Try
        Dim y As Integer = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(BackUpDirectory).Length
        Dim row1 As DataRow
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        While i < y

            row1 = dtSF.Rows(i)

            Dim filenames As String() = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(BackUpDirectory)
            Dim filename As String = filenames(i)


            multiply_SF = row1(0)
            CurveFitTatble = New DataTable()

            Dim TS_Name As String = "TmeStamp" + "_" & i
            Dim AD_Name As String = "AdjustedDemand" + "_" & i

            If i = 0 Then
                adjusteddemandtable.Columns.Add(TS_Name, GetType(Date))
                adjusteddemandtable.Columns(TS_Name).SetOrdinal(i)
                adjusteddemandtable.Columns.Add(AD_Name, GetType(Double))
                adjusteddemandtable.Columns(AD_Name).SetOrdinal(i + 1)

            ElseIf i > 0 Then

                adjusteddemandtable.Columns.Add(TS_Name, GetType(Date))
                adjusteddemandtable.Columns(TS_Name).SetOrdinal(i + 1)
                adjusteddemandtable.Columns.Add(AD_Name, GetType(Double))
                adjusteddemandtable.Columns(AD_Name).SetOrdinal(i + 2)
            End If

            'If row1(0) = filename Then
            CurveFitTatble = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(filename)

            'For Each row As DataRow In CurveFitTatble.Rows()
            Dim row As DataRow
            For j As Integer = 0 To CurveFitTatble.Rows.Count - 1


                row = CurveFitTatble.Rows(j)
                initial_Demand = row(1)
                basecurvestamp = row(0)

                adjusted_Demand = multiply_SF * initial_Demand

                Dim rowa As DataRow = adjusteddemandtable.Rows.Add()

                If i = 0 Then
                    rowa(i) = basecurvestamp
                    rowa(i + 1) = adjusted_Demand

                ElseIf i > 0 Then

                    rowa(i + 1) = basecurvestamp
                    rowa(i + 2) = adjusted_Demand

                End If
            Next

            i = i + 1

        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorMessageBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```